# Need help calling up Custom Fields/Values in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, field

here's the correct code: (Thanks!) (Just had to add '. .' and the value in between when echo)

```
Uploaded by YouTube user: <?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom();
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['ytuser'];
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
    echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.' ">' . $value . "</a><br /><br/>";
?>
```

If you still want to read the problem, here it is below.

Problem:
Currently, I have a **custom field** created called "ytuser" on one of my posts. Inside that field, I have typed in a youtube username (for example: **youtubeuser1**). What I am trying to do now is put that value at the end of a href like this: `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/$value"/>` so that it actually returns the following address: http://www.youtube.com/youtubeuser1 and the text then links to that user's page.

So far I have this:

```
   Uploaded by YouTube user: <?php
      $custom_fields = get_post_custom();
      $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['ytuser'];
      foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
        echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/">' . $value . "</a><br /><br/>";
    ?>
```

But that only gives me a link to "http://www.youtube.com/"

I can't add $value directly to it...

Is there a way I can include the $value as part of the href? So that it can make  the text link go to http://www.youtube.com/$value ?

I know this is a noob question since it can't be that hard.

Comment: Please, don't use "fixed" tags and add the answer in your question: accept the correct answer, and if you have found the correct answer yourself (and it wasn't the one justin gave), add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do `$ytuser = get_post_custom_values("ytuser");` and then call the variable `$ytuser[0];` where you need it like `echo "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/".$ytuser[0]."'>".$ytuser[0]."</a>";`. That should work!

Also, in your code example, you want to switch the " and ' usage in your echo and make sure you echo the user after the YouTube URL and as the link itself (if that's what you want).

Comment: Hey! I didn't know you could add a php value into an echo like that, that's awesome! So I just add '. .' and the value in between? That's exactly what I needed. I didn't use your entire code, just that little part and it worked. So you helped me out. Thanks! Now the value sticks to the href and actually turns into the value I typed in my custom field. Thanks again. :)

Comment: No problem- glad to help! Yes, you just add the . code . and it inserts PHP into any echo string. And make sure to mark this Q as answered too so it goes off the unanswered list :)